# Terraform loops and attached my multiple roles and policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm currently working on a Terraform module to manage AWS Single Sign-On (SSO) permission sets. The goal is to refactor the module to support creating multiple roles within a single AWS account, providing fine-grained access based on user requirements.

**Problem:**

The existing Terraform module is designed to create only one role per account, and I want to extend it to support multiple roles. I've made some modifications to the module, but the output is not as expected. Roles are not being created as intended, and I'm encountering issues with the inline and managed policies. The existing role for that  account, I want keep that.

**Module Refactoring:**

I've refactored the module to make roles an optional list of objects, where each object represents a role. Roles can have either inline policies, managed policies, or both.

```
locals {
  sso_instance_arn = "arn:aws:sso:::instance/ssoins-7354545203"
}

variable "roles" {
  type = list(object({
  name                = string
  inline_policy       = optional(string)
  managed_policy_arns = optional(list(string))
}))

  # make name, inline_policy and managed_policy_arns optional

  default = []
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_permission_set" "custom_permission_set" {
  name             = "Custom-${var.account_id}"
  description      = "Permission set for Custom role for account ${var.account_id}."
  instance_arn     = local.sso_instance_arn
  session_duration = "PT8H"
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_permission_set_inline_policy" "inline_policy" {
  count              = var.inline_policy != null ? 1 : 0
  instance_arn       = local.sso_instance_arn
  inline_policy      = var.inline_policy
  permission_set_arn = aws_ssoadmin_permission_set.custom_permission_set.arn
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_managed_policy_attachment" "managed_policy" {
  for_each           = toset(var.managed_policy_arns) != null ? { for index, value in var.managed_policy_arns : index => value } : {}
  instance_arn       = local.sso_instance_arn
  managed_policy_arn = each.value
  permission_set_arn = aws_ssoadmin_permission_set.custom_permission_set.arn
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment" "assignment" {
  target_type        = "AWS_ACCOUNT"
  target_id          = var.account_id
  principal_id       = var.principal_id
  principal_type     = "GROUP"
  permission_set_arn = aws_ssoadmin_permission_set.custom_permission_set.arn
  instance_arn       = local.sso_instance_arn
}

## This my roles array 
resource "aws_ssoadmin_permission_set" "role_permission_sets" {
  count            = length(var.roles)
  name             = "Custom-${var.account_id}-${var.roles[count.index].name}"
  description      = "Permission set for ${var.roles[count.index].name} role for account ${var.account_id}."
  instance_arn     = local.sso_instance_arn
  session_duration = "PT8H"
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_permission_set_inline_policy" "role_inline_policy" {
  for_each           = length(var.roles) > 0 ? { for index, role in var.roles : index => role.inline_policy } :
  instance_arn       = local.sso_instance_arn
  inline_policy      = each.value != null ? each.value : ""
  permission_set_arn = aws_ssoadmin_permission_set.role_permission_sets[each.key].arn
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_managed_policy_attachment" "role_managed_policy" {
  for_each           = length(var.roles) > 0 ? { for index, role in var.roles : index => role.managed_policy_arns != null ? role.managed_policy_arns : [""] } : {}
  instance_arn       = local.sso_instance_arn
  managed_policy_arn = each.value[0] !=  null ? each.value[0] : ""
  permission_set_arn = aws_ssoadmin_permission_set.role_permission_sets[each.key].arn
}

resource "aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment" "role_assignment" {
  count              = length(var.roles) > 0 ? length(var.roles) : 0
  target_type        = "AWS_ACCOUNT"
  target_id          = var.account_id
  principal_id       = var.principal_id
  principal_type     = "GROUP"
  permission_set_arn = aws_ssoadmin_permission_set.role_permission_sets[count.index].arn
  instance_arn       = local.sso_instance_arn
}
```

Module Usage:

I'm using the module as shown in the example below, defining multiple roles within the roles array.

```
module "dev" {
  source = "../modules/sso-assignment"
  account_id          = "9937364"
  principal_id        = "c245463525252-0081-70aa-7526356353353"
  managed_policy_arns = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecurityAudit"]
  inline_policy = (
    jsonencode({
      Version = "2012-10-17"
      Statement = [
       {
          "Effect" : "Allow",
           "Action" : [
             "s3:DeleteObject"
           ],
           "Resource" : [
              "arn:aws:s3:::oyto/MANUAL/*"
           ]
         },
   ] })
)

   ## I want ths roles array optional
  roles = [
    {
       name = "visitor"
       managed_policy_arns = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/SecurityAudit"]
     },
     {
       name = "system"
       inline_policy = (
         jsonencode({
           Version = "2012-10-17"
           Statement = [
             {
                "Effect" : "Allow",
                "Action" : [
                   "s3:DeleteObject"
                 ],
                 "Resource" : [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::sytem/MANUAL/*"
                 ]
              },
        ] })
      )

    }
  ]
}
```

Issues Encountered:

The output does not match the expected results. Roles are not created as specified in the roles array, and there seems to be an issue with handling inline and managed policies.

Questions:

1. What adjustments should be made to the refactored module to ensure proper handling of multiple roles within one AWS account?
2. Are there any issues with the JSON encoding of inline policies or the usage of jsonencode?
3. How can I correctly iterate over the roles array to create the necessary resources for each role?

Comment: I would start by making use of the [for_each](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each) meta argument, and not handling the special case of their being 0 instances -- the for_each will handle this. Though I'm not directly providing a solution, I think this change will help simplify the issue.

Question: is the correct number of "roles" being created?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, I do not see an issue with how inline policies are created since there is only 1 per role.

As for the managed policies, I believe the issue is to do with the `[0]` reference and possibly with setting: `managed_policy_arn = ""` -- it looks like only the first managed policy in the list would be attached.

Taking your `aws_ssoadmin_managed_policy_attachment` resource:

```
# in this resource I believe you want an attachment per policy_arn
resource "aws_ssoadmin_managed_policy_attachment" "role_managed_policy" {
  for_each = merge([
    for index, role in var.roles : { 
      for policy_arn in coalesce(role.managed_policy_arns, [])
      : "${role.name}_${policy_arn}" => {
        "role_index" : index
        "policy_arn" : policy_arn
      }
    }
  ]...)

  instance_arn       = local.sso_instance_arn
  managed_policy_arn = each.value.policy_arn
  permission_set_arn = aws_ssoadmin_permission_set.role_permission_sets[each.value.role_index].arn
}
```

The intention here is to attach each managed policy to the correct role. In your question you were calling: `managed_policy_arn = each.value[0]...` which would only attach the first policy, and would attempt to attach `""` if there were none.

The `for_each` here loops through **each managed policy** in **each role** and builds a `map` where each value contains both the `policy_arn` and a reference to the role's `index`. For example, if there were two roles and two managed policies per role then this `for_each` would have 4 iterations.

*On a separate note, I would recommend using `for_each` consistently everywhere which would allow you to set the role's `name` as the resource key. This would have prevented me having to set `"role_index" : index` in `each.value` as I could use `each.key` instead.*

`"${role.name}_${policy_arn}"` might appear strange at first, but it is constructed to serve as a unique key in the `map` which is constructed via `merge`. This key is never referenced but is necessary as you cannot `for_each` over `set(object()`.

Since [`merge`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge) takes separate maps as parameters, the [expansion operator (...)](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments) is required on the list of maps to be merged.

---

```
## I want ths roles array optional
```

To address this you can set a [`default`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#declaring-an-input-variable) value of `[]` for your roles variable and let `for_each` and `count` handle the case of an empty list -- and therefore requiring no resource creation.

```
variable "roles" {
  type = list(object({
    name                = string
    inline_policy       = optional(string)
    managed_policy_arns = optional(list(string), [])
  }))

  default = []
}
```

note that `optional(list(string), [])` will prevent having to do: `coalesce(role.managed_policy_arns, [])` -- I have not included this in my answer above.